# Dynamically change translated page title - Svelte

Tags: html, svelte

I've made a page in Svelte. I've provided translations in two languages and it works fine. Now, I want the title on each page to change, and what's more, I want it translated into the current language of the page. I've tried with two-way binding, but I think, that I make something wrong. Minimal example:

```
//../components/meta-title.svelte

<svelte:head>
<title>{title}</title>
</svelte:head>

<script>
export let title = "default title for page"
</script>


//../pages/_layout.svelte

<Meta bind:title={$_('title.companyTitle')} />  //doesn't work

<Navigation items={items}/>

<div>
    <slot/>
</div>

<Footer contact={contact}/>

//../pages/company.svelte
<LeadSection classes="lg:flex-row-reverse -mt-24">
    <div slot="header">
        { $_('pages.company.header') }
    </div>
...
</LeadSection>
```

Any ideas how to make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is: you want to dynamically set the title. To achieve this you don't have to use two way binding. Two way binding is meant to write back to a variable in the parent component. The "variable" you are trying to bind to is not a variable but a store which can't be used for binding. Just pass the title in as a normal prop and it should work:

```
//../components/meta-title.svelte

<svelte:head>
   <title>{title}</title>
</svelte:head>

<script>
   export let title = "default title for page"
</script>


//../pages/_layout.svelte

<Meta title="This is a dynamic title" />

...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
I wonder if it is possible to add the meta-title component only to the layout page, and to pass only the title to other pages? Or I have to add <Meta title="some title"/> to each pagr?

Comment: This depends on wheather you want to set a new title on your other pages. If this is the case you have to add your meta component to each page. If you want to track the current title on other pages I suggest the use of a [svelte store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routing "svelte-routing" then you must have created the separate pages e.g "Home.svelte", "About.svelte".

On each page add this;

```
<svelte:head>
    <title> Title here as a plain text </title>
</svelte:head>
```

You can use a variable if you already have pageName;

```
<svelte:head>
    <title> {pageName} </title>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    let pageName="Home"; 
</script>
```